# Application Memory not clearing in HashMap by remove() or removeAll() method

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I have created a HashMap where millions of key insertions and removals happens continuously(in synchronized manner). However, removals does not remove the memory consumed by the HashMap. Due to this, my application's memory is going high and eventually at one moment, the application shuts down.

Can anyone suggest what should be the approach here to restore the memory upon removal of keys in HashMap.

Insertion:

```
map.put(txnId, new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
```

Removal:

```
Set<String> removalSet = new HashSet<String>();
removalSet.add(entry.getKey());

map.keySet().removeAll(removalSet);
```

Comment: By the way, the `Timestamp` and `Date` classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: What do you mean by the application shutting down?

Comment: While running the jar file, I am passing two parameters, -Xms512m and -Xmx1024m...then getting out of memory exception and that's when the application shuts down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the elements are removed make the reference of `HashMap` as null this would make this object eligible for GC. System.gc() behavior is not guaranteed and should be avoided.

The solution which worked out was:
Use Class WeakHashMap in this case. The objects will automatically be removed if the key is no longer valid [refer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html).

Comment: The problem here is, I am not removing all the keys at once...I'll be keep on adding keys and keep on removing them after some amount of time. However, I guess removal of keys is not ensuring freeing of memory

Comment: Use Class `WeakHashMap<K,V>` in this case. The objects will automatically be removed if the key is no longer valid.  Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/WeakHashMap.html

Comment: This is what I was looking for.
Just a small clarification, do we need to make key=null or we can just remove the key from WeakHashMap and the garbage collector will remove it from memory?

Comment: I think it should be fine unless you face any issue, just remove the keys if they aren't referenced anywhere GC will take care of it. If the solution works please accept this answer

Comment: Unless the map is working as a cache and a missing key only affects performance, weak hash map is not a solution because pruning is non-deterministic, to the point where getting an item right after putting it in the map might return null.

Comment: @kewne so my functionality here is...I'll be storing the key and along with it the current timestamp...then will keep on iterating over the map to check if the timestamp is older than 1 sec, if yes, I should remove it from the Map...so when I am using HashMap, the memory is not getting cleared when I do remove() or removeAll()...

Comment: I’d need to look at more code to understand how the map is being accessed... without more specifics, I can only guess that either something is wrong with removals or a single pass is enough to consume all the memory. It also seems like a sortedSet might fit your use case better.